# Laravel orderBy object attribute

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The 'price' is an object that has an attribute known as list_price.

```
$products =
Product::with(['child','price','variant','thumbnail','image',
'description'])->
take($recperpage)->get();
```

I intend to order by list_price attribute. I can't specify the query as follow:

```
->orderBy('price.list_price','desc')
```

It doesn't work. Any help? I'm using Laravel 5.3.

Comment: Is child,price,variant etc relationship?

Comment: With is used for eager loading relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order the query, you have to add a JOIN on the `prices` tables.

The easier solution is ordering the query result:

```
$products = Product::with(['child','price','variant','thumbnail','image', 'description'])
    ->take($recperpage)->get()->sortByDesc('price.list_price');
```

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepted? This shows other users that the issue is resolved.

Comment: I apologize for the delay as i'm from a different time zone. Thank you for your help.